# Generalize the function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning haskell and try to understand what does generalization mean in the functional programming.

Consider follow code snippet:

```
twiceLifted :: (Functor f1, Functor f) =>
               f (f1 a) -> f (f1 Char)
twiceLifted = (fmap . fmap) replaceWithP

twiceLifted' :: [Maybe String] -> [Maybe Char]
twiceLifted' = twiceLifted
```

As you can see, the first function has not concrete type, functor has to be implemented.

The second function looks more interesting. It reused the first function, but it has a concrete type.
So first function build the ground for the second function.
Is that what generalization in functional programming all about, reused something that already exists and build on top of it?

Comment: `twiceLifted'` only has concrete type because it's declared with that type. If you remove the type declaration, it'll be exactly as general as `twiceLifted`.

Comment: This is a case where thinking in System F, with explicit big-lambda abstraction and type application would make it simpler. Type inference sometimes is a bit too magic, in that it can instantiate a lot of type variables for us, sometimes making the process hard to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalization is about making **concepts** less restrictive. Consider a function that we might have, which goes through a `[Int]` and adds `5` to every element:

```
mapAdd5 :: [Int] -> [Int]
mapAdd5 [] = []
mapAdd5 (x:xs) = (x + 5) : mapAdd5 xs
```

Okay, what if we want to be able to perform *more* than just adding `5` to every element? What if we want go through a whole list and instead multiply every element by `2`?

```
mapMult2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
mapMult2 [] = []
mapMult2 (x:xs) = (x * 2) : mapMult2 xs
```

Something you've probably noticed is that we are in essence applying a function of type `Int -> Int` to every element. Well?

```
mapInts :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
mapInts f [] = []
mapInts f (x:xs) = (f x) : mapInts f xs
```

Great, we've generalized away the internal function now. But what if we want to be able to apply this concept to a `Double -> Double` or even a `String -> String`?

```
mapMore :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapMore f [] = []
mapMore f (x:xs) = (f x) : mapMore f xs
```

What if we don't restrict the function to be of type `a -> a`. That is, we currently force the output type to be the same as the input type. What if they can be different, like `a -> b`? Although it **might** very well be the case that `a` is the same as `b`, but unlike `a -> a`, we don't force it to be so:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = (f x) : map f xs
```

And now we've generalized from `mapAdd5` to `map`.

**Bonus**

What if we don't want to restrict ourselves to using lists? It turns out we can abstract / generalize lists into instances of `Functor`, which are merely things that enable functions to be applied on types that wrap / hold other items. Think about it, that's exactly what a list does!

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

How is `fmap` defined? Its definition will vary based on what type of container `f` you have. However, in the case of lists (also known as `[]`), we have it defined [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-734):

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map
```

Comment: So the introduction of type variables (e.g. `a`) or type constraints (e.g. `Functor`) result in generalization of types. In other words, polymorphism (both parametric and ad-hoc) represents the notion of generalization in the context of types. This is very interesting.